# Pair entry of every nth row with entry of every (n+1)th row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a result table

```
id |       name  | wins
----+-------------------
57 | Paul        | 10
64 | Sven        | 9
62 | Peter       | 9
59 | Marina      | 8
58 | Carlos      | 4
60 | Pamela      | 3
61 | Marcus      | 2
63 | Hank        | 1
```

Where I want to pair every nth entry with every (n+1)th entry, such that the resulting table looks like that:

```
id | name    | id | name
----+-------------------
57 | Paul    | 64 | Sven
62 | Peter   | 59 | Marina
58 | Carlos  | 60 | Pamela
61 | Marcus  | 63 | Hank
```

Which SQL statement would achieve that?

Comment: what is nth and n+1 th entry here? i don't see a pattern

Comment: pair the first row with the second, the third with the fourth, the 5th with the 6th, and so on.

Comment: what specifies the order here so we know the 1st,2nd,..nth row? is it the id column? if so, the expected results are wrong.

Comment: The 1st table was ordered by a third column, which is not visible. The second table is exactly the result which is needed

Comment: you should show the third column then..

Comment: This may be able to be solved using a self join where 3rd column from 1st table is < 3rd column from 2nd table. and then just show table1.Id, table1.name, table2.ID, table2.name and someParingID = otherParingID.

Comment: I have added the 3rd column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Wins DESC) as RowNum
    FROM
       @Table
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte c1
    LEFT JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.RowNum + 1 = c2.RowNum
WHERE
    c1.RowNum % 2 <> 0
```

Generate a ROW_NUMBER to use, seeing you have a third Column replace (SELECT NULL) in the Order by statement with that third column.

Then select all rows that are Odd Row numbers `(remainder of RowNum divided by 2 <> 0 )` and self join back to itself with `RowNum + 1`.  If you have an odd number of Rows you might consider using `LEFT JOIN` so you don't drop off the 1 row that won't have a match.

Comment: Oh, the shifted `LEFT JOIN` makes a lot more sense than the Cartesian with an extra `WHERE` clause that I was about to suggest.